# Javascript - apply validation rules for objects

Tags: javascript

How do I apply a set of validation rules for objects? These are my validation rules.

```
var rules = {  
    p1: {
    "required" : true,
    "pgName" : 'string',
    "type": "template2"
},
    p2 : {
    "required" : true,
    "pgName" : 'string',
    "type": "template2",
    "maxLength": 30
}
}
```

These are the objects I need to apply the validations for. I need to get the validation rules object.

```
var obj = {
p1: {
    "pgName" : 'page1',
},
p2 : {
    "pgName" : 'page2',
    "type": "template"
},
p3 : {
    "pgName" : 'page3',
    "type": "template2"
}
}
```

> I tried to loop through the objects and match the rule with the same key

```
    for (var property in obj){

     for(var key in rules){
       if (typeof obj[property] !== rules[key]){
       console.log(property + ' does not meet the rules');
      } 
     };

 };
```

Comment: anyone able to understand the requirement? Also rules  object seems to be invalid.Object cannot have duplicate key

Comment: why would you loop over the second one?

Comment: You could try [joi](https://github.com/hapijs/joi) as well

Comment: I don't understand what you're trying to do exactly. Why are you checking type?

Comment: I should get the validation rules for type, length, ect.. from another object

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're just looking to get the rules and their objects together you don't need two for loops. This can be done with a single for loop and a conditional. It's much more readable this way.

```js
var rules={p1:{required:!0,name:"string"},p2:{required:!0,name:"string",maxLength:30}},obj={p1:{pgName:"page1"},p2:{pgName:"page2",type:"template"},p3:{pgName:"page3",type:"template2"}};

for(let key in rules) {
if(key in obj) {
  //do something
}
}
```

Proof that both objects are accessible:

```js
var rules={p1:{required:!0,name:"string"},p2:{required:!0,name:"string",maxLength:30}},obj={p1:{pgName:"page1"},p2:{pgName:"page2",type:"template"},p3:{pgName:"page3",type:"template2"}};

for(let key in rules) {
if(key in obj) {
  //do something
  let combined = Object.assign(rules[key], obj[key]);
  console.log( combined );
}
}
```

Furthermore if you're looking to validate your required fields, a simple extension of the above code is pretty easily modified to throw an error if a field is required in the rules but is not within your object.

```js
var rules={p1:{required:!0,name:"string"},p2:{required:!0,name:"string",maxLength:30}, p5: {required: true}},

obj={p1:{pgName:"page1"},p2:{pgName:"page2",type:"template"},p3:{pgName:"page3",type:"template2"}};

for(let key in rules) {
if(key in obj) {
  //do something
}
else {
  if(rules[key]["required"]) throw Error("Required Object Not Available");
}
}
```

The other restrictions are pretty easy to figure out from this point.